# Error on upgrade from rollup 11 to rollup 13 - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When attempting to upgrade from rollup 11 to rollup 13 on our production server we get an error related to the metadata cache as shown below when attempting to upgrade our database. Has anybody seen an error like this before? Any ideas where to start trouble shooting?

21:59:08|  Error| Exception occured during Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationDatabaseHotFixer: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseUpdatesAction failed.
InnerException:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedOptionSetMetadataDataProvider.LoadNormalOptions(IPreloadedMetadataInitializationContext context, Boolean initializeEnumOptionProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedMetadataCacheDataProvider.InitializeOptionSets(IPreloadedMetadataInitializationContext context, LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext organizationContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedMetadataCacheDataProvider.Initialize(IOrganizationContext organizationContext, MetadataContainer container, LoadMasks masks)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.CreateMetadataCacheDataProvider(MetadataContainer container, IOrganizationContext context, LoadMasks masks, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.BuildMetadataCacheFromMetadataContainer(MetadataContainer container, LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.LoadCacheFromDatabaseInternal(LoadMasks masks, CrmDbConnection connection, CrmTransaction transaction, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.LoadCacheFromDatabase(LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheFactory.LoadMetadataCache(LoadMethod method, CacheType type, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.MetadataCache.LoadCache(IOrganizationContext context, Boolean fileOnlyIfExists)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.MetadataCache.GetInstance(IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.ProcessDependencies(FlushCacheOption option, CreateNewCollectorOption createOption)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnEndRequest()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.MetadataPatchService.ProcessMetadataDiffFile(String targetRevision)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DllMethodAction.Execute(Guid organizationId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.ExecuteReleases(ReleaseInfo releaseInfo, Boolean isInstall)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.Install(Int32 languageCode, String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase, Boolean isInstall)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstaller.InstallUpdate(String configurationFilePath, Boolean upgradeDatabase)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.Update.DBUpdateDatabaseInstaller.ApplyDBUpdates(Guid orgId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseUpdatesAction.ApplyDBUpdatesInternal(Guid orgId, String orgUniqueName, String releaseFilePath, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseUpdatesAction.ApplyDBUpdates(Guid orgId, String orgUniqueName, OrganizationOperationType operationType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.InstallDatabaseUpdatesAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
InnerException:
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedOptionSetMetadataDataProvider.LoadNormalOptions(IPreloadedMetadataInitializationContext context, Boolean initializeEnumOptionProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedMetadataCacheDataProvider.InitializeOptionSets(IPreloadedMetadataInitializationContext context, LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext organizationContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.PreloadedMetadataCacheDataProvider.Initialize(IOrganizationContext organizationContext, MetadataContainer container, LoadMasks masks)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.CreateMetadataCacheDataProvider(MetadataContainer container, IOrganizationContext context, LoadMasks masks, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.BuildMetadataCacheFromMetadataContainer(MetadataContainer container, LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.LoadCacheFromDatabaseInternal(LoadMasks masks, CrmDbConnection connection, CrmTransaction transaction, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheLoader.LoadCacheFromDatabase(LoadMasks masks, IOrganizationContext context, CounterList counter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCacheFactory.LoadMetadataCache(LoadMethod method, CacheType type, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.MetadataCache.LoadCache(IOrganizationContext context, Boolean fileOnlyIfExists)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.MetadataCache.GetInstance(IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.ProcessDependencies(FlushCacheOption option, CreateNewCollectorOption createOption)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnEndRequest()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.MetadataPatchService.ProcessMetadataDiffFile(String targetRevision)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a large amount of googling I was able to find the following Microsoft KB which deals with issue. I still don't know the underlying cause of the issue but the script within the KB article did the trick:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2808349

Comment: This helped us with the same issue going on to rollup 18.  So I guess they didn't quite ever fix the problem :-)